# AngularJS factory property isn't being updated in $scope when not using push()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a factory that is retrieving the data from an external source. As soon as i get the data, i use a second factory to filter it by a certain criteria.

The factory property is assigned to scope.

Now when i do this in my factory, it doesn't update the scope:

```
factory.foo = [{id:1,name:'foo'}]; // doesn't work
```

therefor also the filterin in a second factory doesn't work

```
factory.foo = Filter.filter(); // doesn't work
```

while this works:

```
factory.foo.push({id:1,name:'foo'}); // works
```

Does anyone have an idea if this is intended and why it is like this, and how to solve it?

[Full Sample plus plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/360bVD1KvyJgC2O1TG02?p=preview)

```
app.factory('Foo',function(Filter) {
  var factory = {
    foo:[],
    getDataForFoo:function() {
      factory.foo = Filter.filter(); // doesn't work
      //factory.foo = [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:1,name:'foo'}]; // doesn't work
      //factory.foo.push({id:1,name:'foo'}); // works
    }
  };
  return factory;
});

app.factory('Filter',function() {
  var factory = {
    filter:function() {
      var arr = [];
      arr.push({id:1,name:'foo'});
      return arr;
    }
  }
  return factory;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,Foo) {
  $scope.test = 'running';
  $scope.foo = Foo.foo;

  $scope.click = Foo.getDataForFoo;
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/360bVD1KvyJgC2O1TG02?p=preview)

Comment: Is what Simon Belanger says, you lose the reference. I explain it here: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/consuming-services/

Comment: For a full explanation of scope inheritance see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: @piatek i don't think that it's related to the scope inheritance, as i have only one scope here.

Comment: pardon, I've jumped the gun as I've had a similar problem but related to scope earlier!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your factory replace the reference to `Factory.foo`. When your scope is initialized, `$scope.foo` holds a reference to an array (empty). When you call `Foo.getDataForFoo`, it internally changes the reference to `Factory.foo` but your scope still hold a reference to the previous array. This is why using `push` works as it doesn't change the array reference, but the array content.

There are a few ways to fix this. Without going in all the different options, the easiest one is to wrap your `$scope.foo` in a function, returning `Factory.foo`. This way, Angular will detect a reference change in a digest cycle and will update the view accordingly.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,Foo) {
  $scope.test = 'running';
  $scope.foo = function() { return Foo.foo };

  $scope.click = Foo.getDataForFoo
});

// And in the view (the relevant part)

<ul ng-repeat="elem in foo()">
  <li>{{elem.id}} {{elem.name}}</li>
</ul>
<a href="" ng-click="click()">add</a>
```

Comment: thanks for that explanation. is this a good approach...or is there some better/cleaner practise for this?

Comment: It is a good approach when you expect reference changes to something external. As you discovered, one option is to change the content of the array directly (push, splice, etc..) or you can move the function logic to the factory (ie `Foo.foo` is a function returning an array) but you will still have to use `foo()` in your template. Another option is to re-fetch `Foo.foo` after a call to `getDataForFoo` like: `$scope.click = function() { Foo.getDataForFoo(); $scope.foo = Foo.foo; };`. At this point, it's really a matter of preference whether you like using computed properties (function) or not.

Comment: I'd genuinely appreciate the rest of the options on how to do this

Comment: @user2422960 My previous comments briefly explains the other options I could think of at that time

Answer (score 1):

@Simon-Belanger answer is correct and he presents a viable solution.

Another option would be to just empty the array and push new items into it (e.g. for a refresh event), rather than resetting the reference by assigning a new array to it. You can truncate an array by assigning to the length: `myArray.length = 0` and then you can iterate over the new collection to populate new entries via `array.push()`